# How can I capture an optional group in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, regex-group

I have a regex as follows:

```js
    const verseRegex = /(?<chapterBegin>[^\\d+$]*):(?<verseBegin>[^\\d+$]*)-((?<chapterEnd>[^\\d+$]*):)?(?<verseEnd>[^\\d+$]*)/g;
```

I expect the regex to be able to match the following two strings:

- `4:1-13`
- `4:1-5:20`

However the regex is only able to match the first string and group it correctly:

```js
console.log(verseRegex.exec('4:1-13');

[
  '4:1-13',
  '4',
  '1',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  '13',
  index: 0,
  input: '4:1-13',
  groups: [Object: null prototype] {
    chapterBegin: '4',
    verseBegin: '1',
    chapterEnd: undefined,
    verseEnd: '13'
  }
]
```

For the second string `null` is returned. 
I have no explanation for the behavior above. When I remove the optional group and rewrite my regex to be:

```js
const verseRegex = /(?<chapterBegin>[^\\d+$]*):(?<verseBegin>[^\\d+$]*)-(?<chapterEnd>[^\\d+$]*):(?<verseEnd>[^\\d+$]*)/g;
```

now the second string is matched and grouped as expected and the first fails since the `chapterEnd` group is no longer optional.
How can I rewrite my regex so that it matches and groups both strings?

Comment: If it's any help, the following works in Python `r'(?P<chapterBegin>\d+):(?P<verseBegin>\d+)-((?P<chapterEnd>\d+):)?(?P<verseEnd>\d+)'` Although I can't easily check directly myself with Javascript, it might be worth seeing whether something equivalent (maybe `/(?<chapterBegin>\\d+):(?<verseBegin>\\d+)-((?<chapterEnd>\\d+):)?(?<verseEnd>\\d+)/`) will work.

Comment: @alaniwi the javascript version does not work. I have tried the python version and it works though but I have no idea how to write the equivalent of that in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note `[^\\d+$]*` pattern matches any character but a `\`, `d`, `+` and `$` chars. You must have meant to match one or more digit chunks, so you need `\d+`.

You may use

```
/^(?<chapterBegin>\d+):(?<verseBegin>\d+)-(?:(?<chapterEnd>\d+):)?(?<verseEnd>\d+)$/
```

Or, without named capturing groups (for IE, e.g.):

```
/^(\d+):(\d+)-(?:(\d+):)?(\d+)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tEMOjn/1)

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const strs = ['4:1-13','4:1-5:20'];
const rx = /^(?<chapterBegin>\d+):(?<verseBegin>\d+)-(?:(?<chapterEnd>\d+):)?(?<verseEnd>\d+)$/;
for (let s of strs) {
  const results = rx.exec(s);
  console.log(s, results.groups);
}
```

Output:

```
4:1-13 {
  "chapterBegin": "4",
  "verseBegin": "1",
  "chapterEnd": undefined,
  "verseEnd": "13"
}
4:1-5:20 {
  "chapterBegin": "4",
  "verseBegin": "1",
  "chapterEnd": "5",
  "verseEnd": "20"
}
```

Old browsers demo:

```js
var strs = ['4:1-13','4:1-5:20'];
var rx = /^(\d+):(\d+)-(?:(\d+):)?(\d+)$/;
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  var results = rx.exec(strs[i]);
  console.log(strs[i], results);
}
```